# Displaying DOM elements on the web-page while looping over them

Tags: javascript, dom

I am working on a landing page. I have 3 article elements, each of them has the property “display: none” and a class 'art'. I want to display each of them while looping over them. They should appear successively: the previous ones must disappear at each iteration, that is why I have used `var j` in the code below. But JS code displays them after the whole process of looping is completed. How to deal with it? Here: https://codepen.io/user_jacob/pen/oNjqWGg.
Currently, I am doing it like this (which is not working):

```
function makeAppear() {
  var j = list.length-1;
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i].style.setProperty('display', 'block');
    list[j-1].style.setProperty('display', 'none');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In set interval don put `()` just write function name . For looping create one global index then hide all first then show indexed one.

```
let j=0;
function makeAppear() {
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i].style.setProperty('display', 'none');
  }
   list[j].style.setProperty('display', 'block'); 
   if(j<2){ j++;}
   else {j=0}
}

setInterval(makeAppear, 2000);
```